Isar database cause newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints
I am getting 11 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints. Try flutter pub outdated for more information. while trying to get Isar Database.
$ flutter pub add isar isar_flutter_libs path_provider
Resolving dependencies... 
Downloading packages... (11.8s)
  collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
+ ffi 2.1.2
  flutter_lints 3.0.2 (4.0.0 available)
+ isar 3.1.0+1
+ isar_flutter_libs 3.1.0+1
+ js 0.6.7 (0.7.1 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
  lints 3.0.0 (4.0.0 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
  meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
+ path_provider 2.1.4
+ path_provider_android 2.2.9
+ path_provider_foundation 2.4.0
+ path_provider_linux 2.2.1
+ path_provider_platform_interface 2.1.2
+ path_provider_windows 2.3.0
+ platform 3.1.5
+ plugin_platform_interface 2.1.8
  string_scanner 1.2.0 (1.3.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.3 available)
  vm_service 14.2.1 (14.2.4 available)
+ xdg_directories 1.0.4
Changed 13 dependencies!
11 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

$ flutter pub add -d isar_generator build_runner
Resolving dependencies... 
Downloading packages... (11.0s)
+ _fe_analyzer_shared 61.0.0 (73.0.0 available)
+ analyzer 5.13.0 (6.8.0 available)
+ args 2.5.0
+ build 2.4.1
+ build_config 1.1.1
+ build_daemon 4.0.2
+ build_resolvers 2.4.2
+ build_runner 2.4.11 (2.4.12 available)
+ build_runner_core 7.3.1 (7.3.2 available)
+ built_collection 5.1.1
+ built_value 8.9.2
+ checked_yaml 2.0.3
+ code_builder 4.10.0
  collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
+ convert 3.1.1
+ crypto 3.0.3
+ dart_style 2.3.2 (2.3.6 available)
+ dartx 1.2.0
+ file 7.0.0
+ fixnum 1.1.0
  flutter_lints 3.0.2 (4.0.0 available)
+ frontend_server_client 4.0.0
+ glob 2.1.2
+ graphs 2.3.2
+ http_multi_server 3.2.1
+ http_parser 4.0.2 (4.1.0 available)
+ io 1.0.4
+ isar_generator 3.1.0+1
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.1 available)
+ json_annotation 4.9.0
  leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
  lints 3.0.0 (4.0.0 available)
+ logging 1.2.0
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
  meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
+ mime 1.0.5
+ package_config 2.1.0
+ pool 1.5.1
+ pub_semver 2.1.4
+ pubspec_parse 1.3.0
+ shelf 1.4.1 (1.4.2 available)
+ shelf_web_socket 2.0.0
+ source_gen 1.5.0
+ stream_transform 2.1.0
  string_scanner 1.2.0 (1.3.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.3 available)
+ time 2.1.4
+ timing 1.0.1
+ typed_data 1.3.2
  vm_service 14.2.1 (14.2.4 available)
+ watcher 1.1.0
+ web 1.0.0
+ web_socket 0.1.6
+ web_socket_channel 3.0.1
+ xxh3 1.0.1
+ yaml 3.1.2
Changed 46 dependencies!
18 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

$ flutter pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name   Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

dev_dependencies:
build_runner   *2.4.11  *2.4.11     *2.4.11     2.4.12  
flutter_lints  *3.0.2   *3.0.2      4.0.0       4.0.0   

1 dependency is constrained to a version that is older than a resolvable version.
To update it, edit pubspec.yaml, or run `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`.

$ flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
Resolving dependencies... (1.7s)
Downloading packages... 
  _fe_analyzer_shared 61.0.0 (73.0.0 available)
  analyzer 5.13.0 (6.8.0 available)
  build_runner 2.4.11 (2.4.12 available)
  build_runner_core 7.3.1 (7.3.2 available)
  collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
  dart_style 2.3.2 (2.3.6 available)
> flutter_lints 4.0.0 (was 3.0.2)
  http_parser 4.0.2 (4.1.0 available)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.1 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
> lints 4.0.0 (was 3.0.0)
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
  meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
  shelf 1.4.1 (1.4.2 available)
  string_scanner 1.2.0 (1.3.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.3 available)
  vm_service 14.2.1 (14.2.4 available)
Changed 2 dependencies!
16 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

Changed 1 constraint in pubspec.yaml:
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0 -> ^4.0.0

$ flutter pub add isar isar_flutter_libs path_provider
"isar" is already in "dependencies". Will try to update the constraint.
"isar_flutter_libs" is already in "dependencies". Will try to update the constraint.
"path_provider" is already in "dependencies". Will try to update the constraint.
Resolving dependencies... 
Downloading packages... 
  _fe_analyzer_shared 61.0.0 (73.0.0 available)
  analyzer 5.13.0 (6.8.0 available)
  build_runner 2.4.11 (2.4.12 available)
  build_runner_core 7.3.1 (7.3.2 available)
  collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
  dart_style 2.3.2 (2.3.6 available)
  http_parser 4.0.2 (4.1.0 available)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.1 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
  meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
  shelf 1.4.1 (1.4.2 available)
  string_scanner 1.2.0 (1.3.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.3 available)
  vm_service 14.2.1 (14.2.4 available)
Got dependencies!
16 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

How to fix it?
